# При записи данных в хранилище Redux и последующем вытаскивании ее в компонент реакт выдает ошибку "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: reactjs, redux

При получения информации c Api получаю строку, в которой всего одно значение, например 625, записываю его в слайс searcherSlice.js и потом пытаюсь вывести в другом компоненте, но не могу

**компонент SearchForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './SearchForm.css'
import {FaSearch} from 'react-icons/fa';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { totalItemsFound } from '../store/slices/SearcherSlice'

const SearchForm = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [bookData, setData] = useState([]);

  const searchBook=(evt)=>{
    if(evt.key==="Enter")
    {
      axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='+ search +'&key=SECRET_KEY')
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data.totalItems)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Ошибка при запросе к API:', error);
      });

      const searchResult = bookData // строка например 625 - число книг

      dispatch(totalItemsFound(searchResult))

    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className='search-form'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='search-form-content'>
            <div className='search-form'>
              <div className='search-form-elem flex flex-sb bg-white'>
                <input type="text" className='form-control' placeholder='Name of book...'
                  value={search} 
                  onChange={e=>setSearch(e.target.value)}
                  onKeyDown={searchBook}/>
                <button className='flex flex-c'>
                  <FaSearch className='text-light-black' size={28} />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </>
  )
}

export default SearchForm
```

**searcherSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const searcherSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'searcher',
  initialState: {
    value: 0
  },
  reducers: {
    totalItemsFound: state => {
        state.value = state
    }
  }
})

export const { totalItemsFound } = searcherSlice.actions

export default searcherSlice.reducer
```

**компонент BookList.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import './BookList.css';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const BookList = () => {

  const count = useSelector(state => state.searcher.value)
  


  return (
    <div className='BookList'>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="BookList-content flex flex-c">
          Found {count} results
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BookList
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import searcherReducer from './slices/SearcherSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    searcher: searcherReducer
  }
})
```

**ОШИБКИ**

```
serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:14 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at isPlain (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:14:1)
    at _loop_2 (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:78:1)
    at findNonSerializableValue (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:63:1)
    at _loop_2 (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:86:1)
    at findNonSerializableValue (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:63:1)
    at _loop_2 (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:86:1)
    at findNonSerializableValue (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:63:1)
    at _loop_2 (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:86:1)
    at findNonSerializableValue (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:63:1)
    at _loop_2 (serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:86:1)

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:1)
    at updateSlot (react-dom.development.js:15202:1)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:15349:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15821:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19174:1)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:19924:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21618:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
```

Comment: Привидите полный компоненты, как вы получаете данные, как сетите, как достаете. Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас образовался "бесконечный" цикл вызовов

Comment: Привел полные компоненты

Comment: Можете еще дополнить вопрос полным текстом ошибки

Comment: добавил ошибки которые выдает консоль

Comment: На сколько корректна вот эта конструкция `state.value = state`? Вы делаете ссылку на сам объект, в котором есть этот ключ, ссылающийся на себя.

Comment: ну насколько я понял я получаю state из компонента SearchForm и с помощью dispatch меняю значения значения на то которое получил от API или я что-то не так делаю, точно не уверен...

Comment: Попробуйте так заменить `totalItemsFound: (state, action) => { state.value = action.payload }`

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало! Вы мой спаситель

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка вызвана тем, что вы создаете объект с "бесконечной" вложенностью.

```
totalItemsFound: state => {
    state.value = state
}
```

**state** - объект
в объекте **state** вы создаете ключ **value**, которому присваиваете **state**
т.к. **state** существует в одном экземпляре, в **value** хранится ссылка на **state**, у которого есть **value**, где ссылка на **state** и так далее до бесконечности.

У методов redux tookit, первым параметром передается текущий **state**, второй параметр **action** - входящие данные, которые надо обработать в хранилище.

**action** это объект, который содержит ключ **payload** - данные, которые необходимо сохранить в хранилище.

Для того что бы исправить ошибку, необходимо добавить второй параметр в метод **totalItemsFound**

```
totalItemsFound: (state, action) => { 
    state.value = action.payload;
}
```